# Position of anonymous function’s parameters in SML’s foldl

Tags: sml

I need to write a function that takes a list of strings and finds the largest string in the list. In case of tie, it should return string closest to the end of the list. The catch is it needs to iterate through the list using List.foldl and cannot use recursive calls except for those in the library function of List,foldl.
The following code works fine.

```
fun longest_string2 str_list =
     List.foldl(fn (x, acc) => if String.size x >= String.size acc then x else acc) "” str_list
```

If I run `longest_string2 ["Apple", "ball", "Bpple”];` in REPL, I get `val it = "Bpple" : string`
However, if I reverse the arguments of anonymous function as below I get `val it = "Apple" : string`.
Since the anonymous function is accessing the elements by name and not position, why does this makes difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of List.foldl is

```
fun foldl (f: 'a*'b->'b) (acc: 'b) (l: 'a list): 'b =
  case l of
    [] => acc
  | x::xs => foldl f (f(x,acc)) xs
```

If you reverse arguments of the anonymous function, your function becomes the following: (correct me if I misinterpreted your question)

```
fun longest_string2 str_list =
     List.foldl(fn (acc, x) => if String.size x >= String.size acc then x else acc) "” str_list
```

If your pass `["Apple", "ball", "Bpple”]` as argument to `longest_string2` now, the `foldl` function will pattern match your list with x::xs, where `x` is “Apple” and `xs` is ["ball", "Bpple”]. When you compute the updated accumulator using `f(x, acc)`, `x` and `acc` gets swapped. In other words, in your anonymous function (with reversed arguments), you would be assuming that the first argument would be `””` and the second argument would be `Apple` but the implementation of List.foldl will pass `f(“Apple”, “”)`. In this case, your anonymous function will label `“Apple”` as `“acc”` and `“”` as `“x”`.

Answer (score 1):

@3123 has most answered the question, but has not directly addressed this statement in the question.

> Since the anonymous function is accessing the elements by name and not
> position, why does this makes difference?

`foldl` takes a function which takes a *tuple* as its argument, which is positional.

We could define a fold function which takes a record as its argument instead if we really wanted to achieve this:

```
fun namedFold _ acc [] = acc
  | namedFold f acc (x::xs) =
      namedFold f (f {acc=acc, x=x}) xs;
```

And then call it as:

```
namedFold (fn { acc, x } => acc + x) 0 [1,2,3,4]
```

Or as:

```
namedFold (fn { x, acc } => acc + x) 0 [1,2,3,4]
```

And get the same result.

But then the type of `namedFold` is `fn :({acc: 'a, x: 'b} -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a` and it becomes essentially impossible to easily pass existing functions to it. With `foldl` defined the way it is, we can easily rewrite that previous called to `namedFold` as:

```
foldl op+ 0 [1,2,3,4]
```

Because `op+` has the same signature as the first argument to `foldl`.